# Can I kill a thread that is waiting for TCP connection to come in?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I have a application where a thread is listening for TCP connections, and will need to be killed. What is the best way to do this? I know that Thread.stop is deprecated, is interrupting the thread enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a reference to a `ServerSocket` you can call its [`close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) method.  This will cause the Thread waiting on `accept()` to throw a `SocketException`.

Note that you probably don't want to expose a reference to the socket itself; you should probably add a method to your server code named `shutdownServer()` or similar which does this itself.

Answer (score 1):

Generally - yes, you should use [Thread.interrupt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) and a shared variable.  In your particular example, you can just close the Socket to cause the thread to return immediately.  Read about it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a checked exception (and `accept()` doesn't declare it), so whatever might happen by interrupting the thread you should not expect to be catching that when calling `ServerSocket.accept()`.  I would have to try it to see whether interrupting the thread has any effect at all.  I would guess that it doesn't.

Comment: Ok yeah I tried it, interrupting the thread does not preempt the call to `accept()`, it just keeps waiting.

Comment: ...as long as he's not using java nio.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a "stop" variable that the thread checks after each connection. Then connect to the thread's port to wake it up.

Another approach would be to set a timeout with a call to `soTimeout()` and check the "stop" variable after each connection and when the timeout occurs. You probably don't want to set the timeout too short. This means the thread would not stop immediately, so that might not work for you if a quick shutdown is required.

You could also call close() directly on the ServerSocket if possible as mentioned by Mark Peters.